# Profiling JNI applications

Tags: java, memory, profiling, java-native-interface

How do we track memory allocation in a Java application that makes use of JNI layer. More specifically if the underlying C code does some memory allocation, can we track those allocations using some profiler [Eclipse/Netbeans].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to track those allocations using a native framework like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.java).

[Running a JNI application in the Sun VM under Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451282/running-a-jni-application-in-the-sun-vm-under-valgrind)

Comment: a very good post on the subject: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.java/java/6.0/MonitorDebug/3-ProfilingNativeMemoryUsage/player.html